# How to get all the jobs scheduled with different names in node-schedule?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to get the list of all the jobs that are scheduled by node-schedule

```
 var scheduleIds = schedule.scheduleJob(scheduleId,rule, function() {
  console.log("HELLO")
   })
```

here scheduleId is a unique key and there are multiple jobs running with different names. How can I find a job from its name and cancel it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
var scheduleIds = schedule.scheduleJob(scheduleId,rule, function() {
console.log("HELLO")
})
```

The schedule object that is created contains all the names of the jobs that are scheduled.

Comment: When I console.log the `schedule` object, the result is this: 
`{ [Function: scheduleJob]
  bindAsync: { [Function] __isPromisified__: true },
  toStringAsync: { [Function] __isPromisified__: true },
  callAsync: { [Function] __isPromisified__: true },
  applyAsync: { [Function] __isPromisified__: true } }
`
It'd be great if you tell how to get those names and use them?

Comment: schedule.scheduledJobs is an array that will show you all the jobs that are scheduled. Just do this
    console.log(schedule.scheduledJobs)

Comment: `scheduledJobs` is (at least now), an object: `{[jobName: string]: schedule.Job}`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same query and this is what worked for me. I am using `[node-schedule v2.1.0][1]` and this is 8y11m after the question was posted. So I am not sure if the API has changed a bit since the above answers.

To get access to scheduled jobs, use code like below:

```js
const schedule = require('node-schedule'); // import module
const {scheduledJobs} = schedule; // get access to scheduled jobs
console.log({scheduledJobs}); // prints {scheduledJobs: {<job1 object>}, {job2 object>}, ...} to console
```

To access a specific job by name, use code similar to this:

```js
console.log(scheduledJobs['hello123']); // prints Job object by name "hello123", if it exists, to console
```

The above snippet assumes that a job with name 'hello123' has been already scheduled. To cancel this job, one can use a code similar to this:

```js
const hello123job = scheduledJobs['hello123']; // returns Job object corresponding to job with name 'hello123'
const status = schedule.cancelJob(hello123job); // Cancels the job and returns Boolean true on success
```